# Flutter: is there a way for a deep child widget to ask a parent's FutureBuilder to re-fetch data?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, sqflite, flutter-futurebuilder

My app keeps the user's favorite food in a SQLite database. A top-level widget, `MyApp`, loads this data using a `FutureBuilder` and then hoists it deeper using a `Provider`.

There's a `FoodPage` page that can manage foods. When you "save" on that page, it writes to the SQLite. However, `MyApp` doesn't reload its future.

`FoodPage` is always reached using several `Navigator.push(context, ...)` calls. That means I'm several hops away from the top-level `MyApp`, so I'm unsure how to request a "re-fetch" from here.

If I were doing all my work directly in `MyApp`, I'd be able to call `setState(() {})` to refresh its FutureBuilder. However, I can't because I'm in a different widget.

Also, I'm several nested `Navigator.push`'s deep, so doing `Navigator.pop().then(...)` wouldn't really help me here.

Is my only option to do the clunky thing and reload the SQLite foods on every page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refresh the data in the top-level widget, `MyApp`, after a user has added or updated a food in `FoodPage`, you can use a callback function to notify `MyApp` that the data has changed.

Here is an example of how you can use a callback function to achieve this:

In `FoodPage`, define a callback function that takes a bool parameter indicating whether the data has changed:

```dart
class FoodPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(bool) onDataChanged;

  FoodPage({required this.onDataChanged});

  // ...
  
  void _saveFood() {
    // Save the food to SQLite
    // Notify the parent widget that t
he data has changed
    onDataChanged(true);
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

In `MyApp`, pass the callback function to FoodPage and use it to trigger a refresh of the data:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _fetchData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => FoodsProvider(snapshot.data),
            child: CupertinoApp(
              home: Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    await Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => FoodPage(
                          onDataChanged: (bool dataChanged) {
                            if (dataChanged) {
                              // Reload the data from SQLite
                              // This will trigger a rebuild of MyApp
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('Open FoodPage'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

By passing the `onDataChanged` callback function to `FoodPage`, you can use it to trigger a refresh of the data in `MyApp` when the user adds or updates a food. When the callback function is called, you can reload the data from `SQLite`, which will trigger a rebuild of `MyApp` and refresh the data in the UI.

Comment: That's a handy approach, it's pretty much what I want. I have one more point to ask: do you think it'd be bad practice if I put `onDataChanged` itself into a Provider? I'm several `Navigator.push`'s deep, and I'm hoping to avoid passing this callback through each route.